# Update and reload UITableView after completion of personal goals

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, swift4

I'm building some kind of Todo List app. And easy to use tool that helps build a routine of positive, habits, set personal goals, track your progress. But when I created a user Sets Personal Goals which he/she has to slide to the left which is a number adds up to the user's progress. I have managed to create that. But when the user finishes goals it says COMPLETE GOAL, which is fine but I want the Tableview Cell to update and remove the COMPLETION VIEW!

The problem is it does not update data from uitableview. Please help me and I really appreciate your time.

```
//GCell.swift

func configureCell(goal: Goal) {
    self.goalDescriptionLbl.text = goal.goalDescription
    self.goalDescriptionLbl2.text = goal.goalDescription2
    
    self.goalProgressLbl.text = String(describing: goal.goalProgress)
    
    if goal.goalProgress == goal.goalCompletion {
        self.completionView.isHidden = false
    } else {
        self.completionView.isHidden = true

    }

    //GVC.swift

    func setProgress(atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else { return }
    
    let chosenGoal = goals[indexPath.row]
    
    if chosenGoal.goalProgress < chosenGoal.goalCompletion {
        chosenGoal.goalProgress = chosenGoal.goalProgress + 1
    } else {
        return
    }
    
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        print("Successfully set progress")
    } catch {
        debugPrint("Could not set progress: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

    func removeGoal(atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else { return }
    managedContext.delete(goals[indexPath.row])
    
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        print("Successfully removed goal!")
    } catch {
        debugPrint("Could not remove: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
{
    let addAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        self.setProgress(atIndexPath: indexPath)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        success(true)
    })
    addAction.image = UIImage(named: "Add1")
    self.fetchCoreDataObjects()
    
    addAction.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411765, green: 0.9607843137, blue: 0.9803921569, alpha: 1)
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [addAction])
} }

// cellForRowAt indexPath

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "goalCell") as? GoalCell else {
        return UITableViewCell() }
    
    let goal = goals[indexPath.row]
    
    // pass class(Object) from GoalCell.swift file
    // Core Data NS fetch - 4
    cell.configureCell(goal: goal)
    
    // Did select 2
    cell.goalDescriptionLbl2?.text = ""
    
    return cell
}
    //managedContext 
    func fetch(completion: (_ complete: Bool) -> ()) {
    guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else { return }
    
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Goal>(entityName: "Goal")
    
    do {
        goals = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        print("Successfully fetched data.")
        completion(true)
    } catch {
        debugPrint("Could not fetch: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        completion(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220193/discussion-on-question-by-iyezan-update-and-reload-uitableview-after-completion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: goalpost model]

First, change your model as the img showed above.

Second, change your `setProgress` function code in ``GoalsVC``` as:

```
    func setProgress(atIndexPath indexPath : IndexPath) {
        guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else { return }
        let selectedGoal = goals[indexPath.row]
        if selectedGoal.goalProgressValue < selectedGoal.goalCompletionValue - 1 {
            selectedGoal.goalProgressValue = selectedGoal.goalProgressValue + 1
        } else {
            // By the time the code executing, goal is met.
            selectedGoal.goalProgressValue = selectedGoal.goalProgressValue + 1
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                // the code in the block is all about hiding the completion view
                selectedGoal.goalCompleteViewShowed = true
                do {
                    try managedContext.save()
                    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
                } catch {
                    debugPrint("Couldn't set progress. \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
            return
        }
        
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch {
            debugPrint("Couldn't set progress. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

Third, change your `configureCell` function in `GoalCell` as:

```
    func configureCell(goal : Goal) {
        self.goalDescriptionLabel.text = goal.goalDescription
        self.goalTermLabel.text = goal.goalType
        self.goalProgressLabel.text = "\(goal.goalProgressValue)"
        self.goalIndex = goal.index
        
        if lastIndex == nil {
            lastIndex = 0
        } else {
            lastIndex = goalIndex
        }
        
        // I think you might just want the completionView to show again since it is just for the notification purpose.
        if goal.goalProgressValue == goal.goalCompletionValue && !goal.goalCompleteViewShowed { 
            self.goalCompleteView.isHidden = false
        } else {
            self.goalCompleteView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

The code is just tested with your project that is uploaded in the github.

Comment: My email address is dylzjl@gmail.com. I don't know if the SO community allows this but I really do some software consulting job on iOS right now. You certainly can consult me with some tough task that you cannot easily handled. But for this sort of problem I do suggust you just spending more time on Apple's documentation and sample code. And SO is always a great community to reach if you need a hand at the very first place.

Comment: Hi Zhoujialei, this is awesome. I have been looking someone who can help me incase if  get stack on any project. ill certainly can consult you with some tough task that I cannot easily handled. :)

Comment: Emmmm, OK I will upload my edited project. Wait a minute. Don't forget to upvote my answer and accept it if it is working.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. It does what I wanted and also, I know I'm being extra! but at the moment only goalCompleteView is disappearing. is there any the Cells disappear as well?.

Comment: This is the last question please.

Comment: Vote up and accept my answer please. I'll do it after you do that since it's really another problem

Comment: Sorry I didn't get, how would I accept your answer?

Comment: That's already an reward for me. I would push my code in a minute.

Comment: Hi Zhoujialei. I hope you doing well. You never get back to me. And also I have sent an email.